# Get unique values using XSLT 1.0 (Without using XSL:Key)

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath, xslt-1.0

I'm facing a typical problem while am getting the Unique list using XSLT 1.0.

**Sample XSLT:**

```
<xsl:if test="$tempVar = 'true'">
    <xsl:variable name="filePath" select="document($mPath)" />
    // Do something
    // I can't implement this using "Muenchian Method". 
    // Since, I can't declare <xsl:key> inside of <xsl:if>
    // There is no chance to declare <xsl:key> on top.
    // I should get unique list from here only
</xsl:if>
```

**filepath** variable would contain XML as follows:-

```
<Root>
    <Data id="102">
        <SubData>
            <Info code="abc">Information 102</Info>
        </SubData>
    </Data>
    <Data id="78">
        <SubData>
            <Info code="def">Information 78</Info>
        </SubData>
    </Data>
    <Data id="34">
        <SubData>
            <Info code="abc">Information 34</Info>
        </SubData>
    </Data>
    <Data id="55">
        <SubData>
            <Info code="xyz">Information 55</Info>
        </SubData>
    </Data>
    <Data id="86">
        <SubData>
            <Info code="def">Information 86</Info>
        </SubData>
    </Data>
    <Data id="100">
        <SubData>
            <Info code="xyz">Information 100</Info>
        </SubData>
    </Data>
</Root>
```

**Output:** Unique list of **code** should be

```
abc
def
xyz
```

Thanks

Comment: You claim that keys and Muenchian grouping can't be used in your case -- is simply not true. You'll now learn how to do it. :) +1 for asking :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> <xsl:if test="$tempVar = 'true'">
>     <xsl:variable name="filePath" select="document($mPath)" />
>     // Do something
>     // I can't implement this using "Muenchian Method". 
>     // Since, I can't declare <xsl:key> inside of <xsl:if>
>     // There is no chance to declare <xsl:key> on top.
>     // I should get unique list from here only
> </xsl:if>
> ```

**It isn't true that one cannot use `<xsl:key>` and the `key()` function in such circumstances**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
 xmlns:ext="http://exslt.org/common">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:key name="kcodeByVal" match="@code" use="."/>

 <xsl:variable name="tempVar" select="'true'"/>

 <xsl:variable name="vrtfFilePath">
    <Root>
        <Data id="102">
            <SubData>
                <Info code="abc">Information 102</Info>
            </SubData>
        </Data>
        <Data id="78">
            <SubData>
                <Info code="def">Information 78</Info>
            </SubData>
        </Data>
        <Data id="34">
            <SubData>
                <Info code="abc">Information 34</Info>
            </SubData>
        </Data>
        <Data id="55">
            <SubData>
                <Info code="xyz">Information 55</Info>
            </SubData>
        </Data>
        <Data id="86">
            <SubData>
                <Info code="def">Information 86</Info>
            </SubData>
        </Data>
        <Data id="100">
            <SubData>
                <Info code="xyz">Information 100</Info>
            </SubData>
        </Data>
    </Root>
 </xsl:variable>

 <xsl:variable name="vfilePath"
      select="ext:node-set($vrtfFilePath)"/>

 <xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:if test="$tempVar = 'true'">
     <xsl:for-each select="$vfilePath">
      <xsl:for-each select=
       "*/*/*/Info/@code
                    [generate-id()
                    =
                     generate-id(key('kcodeByVal',.)[1])
                     ]
       ">
       <xsl:value-of select="concat(.,' ')"/>
      </xsl:for-each>
     </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:if>
 </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when this transformation is applied to any XML document (not used in this example), the wanted, correct result is produced**:

```
abc def xyz
```

Comment: Hi Dimitre, I was waiting for your solution too. Finally you have posted. Thanks for it. I have a small doubt:- **`<xsl:key name="kcodeByVal" match="@code" use="."/>`** What exactly this LOC is doing, at this point? Please explain. 

**Note:** For my instance, **XML** is not applying on whole **XSLT**. **XML** is getting as document with in the **IF** condition only.

Comment: @SivaCharan: An `<xsl:key>` can only be a global instruction -- this doesn't at all mean it can't be referenced by a `key()` function anywhere in the code, within or not within conditional instructions. @Michael Kay is right that you need to read about keys and need to understand them. Right now you don't have this knowledge and understanding and the main merit of any answer must be to make you aware of this fact. Because, without this necessary knowledge you even can't understand the any solution that uses keys.

Comment: @SivaCharan: In particular, the instruction: **`<xsl:key name="kcodeByVal" match="@code" use="."/>`** defines a key (index), gives it a name, specifies which nodes to index (`@code`) and what should be used as the indexing (key) value -- the string value of the matched node in this case. This is just a definition -- it doesn't cause any indexing, until a `key()` function references this particular key. Only then is indexing done -- on the *current document*. Please, read a good XSLT book.

Comment: Thats perfect. It worked Dimitre. Thank you sooo much for explaining in detail......

Answer (score 2):

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="//Data[
                             not(
                                */Info/@code = preceding-sibling::Data/*/Info/@code
                             )
                         ]/*/Info/@code"/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="@*">
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        <xsl:text>&#xD;</xsl:text>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thanks Kirill.. this is also worked. But I will use Dimitre solution. +1 for nice answer.

Answer (score 1):

Your reason for not using the Muenchian method or xsl:key is spurious. It will work perfectly well. You have probably failed to understand that when you declare a key definition, it is not specific to one particular source document, it allows you to use the key() function against any source document.

Comment: If am not wrong, we can't declare **<xsl:key>** inside the **<xsl:if>**. Since am getting the xml (i.e., document) inside the if condition. Please suggest if any.